# IMvxServiceProducer and IMvxServiceConsumer missing from latest NuGet

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm using the latest NuGet packages for MvvmCross CrossCore, Hot Tuna, Location and Picture Plug ins, but I can't seem to find in the object browser the IMvxServiceProducer and IMvxServiceConsumer classes that are used in many examples.  Doing a search for RegisterServiceInstance, I found Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxIoCExtensions.  Did the two interfaces go away in place of something simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those interfaces were used in many v1 and vNext samples, but in v3 they have all been replaced with `Mvx.Resolve<T>` service location, or with cleaner constructor injection.

All the examples in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/ and in the N+1 videos have been updated to use the newer APIs.

For a full explanation of v3's service location and IoC see: [Instantiation of ViewModels and Service classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967454/instantiation-of-viewmodels-and-service-classes/16980207#16980207)

Comment: Awesome.  I found the "N=9 Get the Message" video perfect for solving the problem of sharing a service (like the location service) across devices using the pub/sub model https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQdvrWWzkIk