# Mvx container and unit testing

Tags: mono, xamarin, mvvmcross

I need to override Mvx container behavior, to inject some mock objects when my real code ask to container (as a service locator) to resolve some interface.

What are the minimum interface required to deal with that ? Actually, I didnt understand how `IMvxIoCProvider` and `IMvxServiceProvider` interfaces works.

Looking up to `BaseIoCSupportingTest` example in MvxMod project, I could notice there's another interface required: `IMvxServiceProviderRegistry`. Why do we need that ?

How can I simply register a  `IMvxIoCProvider` which should wrap `MvxSimpleIoCContainer` when running a context of Unit Testing?

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

MvxMod was a fork of the main MvvmCross project based on a vNext (v2) version of the code. Assuming you are actually using the latest version - v3...

The MvvmCross v3 IoC/Service Locator implementation is discussed in depth in [Instantiation of ViewModels and Service classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967454/instantiation-of-viewmodels-and-service-classes) (currently also maintained on [the MvvmCross Wiki](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control))

Further:

- this article - http://blog.fire-development.com/2013/06/29/mvvmcross-enable-unit-testing/ - introduces some testing examples
- the N+1 video N=29 shows some more examples - https://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/
- although Twitter has now turned off the RSS search data service, the TwitterSearch test harness shows some useful testing samples - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.Test